# Docker-compose ssh agent forwarding

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying set up a ssh agent forwarding in a docker container mounting the path from the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` env var in docker-compose.yml:

```
volumes:
  - "${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}:/keyring"
```

The docker-compose utility complains:

> Cannot create container for service app: create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters

Is `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` empty for docker-compose? How can I get this to work?

Comment: What is the value of `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in the shell where you're running `docker-compose up` from?  Does it work if you manually put the literal value into the file?

Comment: @JeremyHuiskamp the value is `/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh`, putting it manually would help, I wanted to take it from the var

Comment: Hmm, according to https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution and https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3 you are doing it correctly from what I can tell.  Can you post your entire docker-compose.yml?  What if you use the long syntax for the volume?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the variable SSH_AUTH_SOCK was empty. I was calling the docker-compose using `sudo`, which does not transfer your environment variables. According to the sudo manpages you should use `sudo -E` for this. In short use:

```
sudo -E docker-compose -f [compose_file.yml] up
```

You didn't share your docker-compose file, but don't forget to set the SSH_AUTH_SOCK variable in the container as well.

```
    environment:
      SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /keyring
```